Are Genesis Chapters 10 and 11 split incorrectly?
Regarding the Tower of Babel narrative...
I have posted elsewhere about the timeline problem of Babel happening only ~100 years after the flood. Population, technology, etc. issues are all raised with such a short time frame.
I have found an alternate theory that I'd like to get feedback on.
What if...Chapter 10 should end AFTER the Babel account, with Chapter 11 beginning before Shem's genealogy? This would place Babel after the language dispersion of the families, so 'whole earth' would be using the other definition more like whole area or country - this is not an uncommon interpretation.
Babel would be the end of the section that contains Nimrod (Ham's descendant), who may be the start of the clan that built Babel (Babel is mentioned with him). I have seen him mentioned as the one who built the tower. That then places Peleg (Shem's descendant) in a different section - and his name 'Division' could refer to something else. It usually means something more like 'cut into parts' rather than scatter, so that would also fit better. It is his birth time that causes the short time issue.
I realize this is not the traditional understanding. However, it would clear up issues on the timeline. It could also place Babel at a time closer to archeological findings of when this type of brick was used.
My only other seemingly viable option is that this is an illustration/parable/polemic that was inserted here and not a literal event - at least not in this time frame. I'm tagging this as contradiction because the timeline seems to contradict...well...math, history, and population growth.
Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

The chapter divisions are not original but added over a millennium later.  Ignore them.

@Dottard Thank you for answering me - again. It seems that almost everyone does rely on those chapter divisions to connect Babel to Peleg. It astounds me that the math doesn't seem to have triggered any general change in understanding over the centuries! This is both Christian and Jewish understanding going back a long time. It makes me feel like I'm missing something everybody else sees. I thought I should start a new question before I got into trouble on the previous one.

These questions are all based on unverified assumptions.  Do not get too carried away by these tacit assumption - they are unverified.  We cannot be sure that Babel is even linked to Peleg - do not get distracted by it.  There are more important matters to tackle

@Dottard Can you tell I've been losing sleep over this? It really has given me problems with the truth of the Bible. I keep seeing people tie Babel to Peleg because of the division name thing. But I also see Babel tied to Nimrod, which makes more sense for it taking place later and not being tied to Peleg's age.  It does seem like Babel should be with the genealogy that mentions him, not in the next chapter.

Again, the chapters divisions have no meaning for the original text.  Ignore them.

@Dottard I guess it's like when a preacher says something in a sermon and you think, "I don't think that's what that means..." Even well known rabbis and pastors can understand things differently.

Ha! I found somebody who agrees with me! https://davidtue.com/bad-chapter-breaks-result-poor-understanding/

The bible says that Nimrod built Nineveh. It doesn't say that he built Babel. It says that he had his centre in Babel. Like all the rest of the humans then had. Nimrod would have built Nineveh, and the other cities mentioned, after the language confusion and dispersal from Babel.

@Dottard Although the chapter divisions are much later addition, Torah scrolls (at least since the Dead Sea Scrolls) have always had spaces separating between new subjects. There is a space the chronology at the end of chapter 10 and the story of the Tower of Babel. Indicating that it is a different subject.

@conceptualinertia I saw the Torah had the chapter break there, also. That is the problem. Nimrod who it says founded Babel is BEFORE in Chapter 10. Then a chapter break. Then Babel and the other genealogy which is a different son of Noah. This is why it makes no sense to me, besides that not being enough time for them to be building a tower after the flood. The timeline isn't logical. Do you have an explanation for that?

@conceptualinertia I now understand what you're saying. Babel IS separated out as its own topic. So that may not even be tightly chronological - it could have been something that happened with Nimrod or descendants later down the line.

Regardless of the chapter breaks (ignore these) there is a "chronological dislocation" that takes place in Genesis 10 and 11 that's completely agreed by theologians. Genesis 10 in going through genealogies jumps a long way forward in time to show these with some very brief commentary as it goes. This is very similar to the structure used in the book of chronicles when it does genealogies. The section in chapter 11 then very clearly jumps back in time (how far isn't clear) but back to the point where there is one language and babel is being built.

This isn't a mistake its a literary design pattern and it's fairly consistent through the early chapters of Genesis which follows a repeating cyclical pattern of creation followed by fall. The basic structure is 1) (New) creation 2) Sin/Fall 3) Genealogies that result 4) Move to/from East(Eden) to build an "עִיר" (city). Go back and read Cain and Abel story and you'll see it follows the same basic pattern as Ham/Nimrod Babel. Cain Sins - Genealogies - Cain and his descendants go east to build a city called Enoch. Same as Gen 10-11. Ham sins - Geneolgies - try to come back from east build Babel

It is important to highlight that, if Babel was in fact linked to Peleg – which is a mere assumption, although it is possible, considering his etymology – it does not necessarily have to be linked to her birth. Take Methuselah for example, whose name, which means "His death shall send", was a clear prophecy of the Flood, which occurred in the exact year of his death. Perhaps Peleg was also a prophetic name, and the "division", that is, Babel, would only happen at his death or at any date after his birth, which gives a greater interval for the event. He passed away 340 years after the flood, which may be a more acceptable time for humanity to grow and develop again. I also recommend that you look at the numbers in the LXX, which give 531 years  for Peleg's birth and 870 for his death, much more acceptable dates that would not pose any problems in terms of population.
I think these would be more reasonable solutions to the problem than just unlinking Babel from Peleg but keeping her linked to Nimrod. Although of course Genesis isn't always in precisely chronological order, I don't think changing the order here will solve much. Peleg was the 4th generation after the flood, Nimrod was only the 2nd, so if you detach Babel from Peleg, you have an even shorter period of time for the events to occur. Unless you then also unlink her from Nimrod, which would make any dating impossible.

Hello, L. Rodrigues. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Well, besides perhaps the data on the etymology  of Methuselah, which I took from his article in Wikipedia, everything else can be easily attested in the biblical reading of the two chapters in question, and the sum of the ages given in such. For the LXX ages, just add 100 years to each generation, plus 130 from Cainan's extra generation. There aren't many secret, so I wasn't more specific and detailed, as I thought it would be unnecessary

When I read this I see the tower being built in the first 70 years, given it is only made of bricks and mortar. Which descendants or generations are present is uncertain, however I believe the "scattering" occurs before Peleg is born.
Chapter 11 gives the timeline of after the flood, Tower of Babel, and then the birth of Peleg leading to Abram. The description "Earth was divided" is a direct reference to the 4.2ky climate event. This saw the world divided into drought affected and flood affected areas, leading to mass migration of peoples seeking better conditions. The "divided" could also describe the Repeller of the Amorites wall, a 100 mile wall constructed across central Mesopotamia to stop northern movement of peoples southward.
This difficult time period lasted close to 300 years, longer than Peleg's lifetime.

I had another question related to this but here is the issue.. You seem to think there was enough of a population in 70 years from 3 original birthing couples to not only survive but manage to plan and organize a large tower from FIRED straw containing bricks (not a simple endeavor as you seem to think) and mortar. The math doesn't add up, for one thing. There are calculations online showing this. Plus they just got off the ark and already are revolting against God?
Also, the previous genealogy says people already spread out with different languages.
